# Blazor highlight selected button and remove highlight from others

Tags: blazor-webassembly, c#-7.0

I'm using a custom object `TestObject` that that has an Id (int), Text(string) and other Details.

These are populated using `@foreach` which then renders a component for each `TestObject`.

When the button is selected, that button should be highlighted by applying a style in the component, any other button's highlight removed and the 'other details' shown on the page.

The 'other details' are switching correctly, but I cannot get the button to highlight properly, and other buttons to remove highlight (1st one is highlighted by default).

I have tried passing in a bool whether the button should be highlighted or not, including whether it's selected in the `TestObject` object and passing in the selected button's `Id` but none of these are updating the buttons. The parent page is calculating this correctly but not passing to the components to re-render.

TestObject.cs

```
public class TestObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

TestComponent.razor

```
<button @onclick="Click" class="test"style="@styles">
    @Text
</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Selected { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int SelectedId{ get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> CallBack { get; set; }

    private string styles = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CheckIfSelected();
    }
    private void Click()
    {
        CallBack.InvokeAsync(Id);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void CheckIfSelected()
    {
        //if (Selected)
        if(Id == SelectedId)
        {
            styles = "background-color: grey;";
        }
        else
        {
            styles = "background-color: white;";
        }
    }
}
```

TestParent.razor

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: white;">
    @foreach (var T in TestObjects)
    {
        <TestComponent Id="@T.Id" Text="@T.Text" Selected="@T.Selected" SelectedId="@SelectedTestObject.Id" CallBack="SelectObject" />
    }

    <hr />
    <div>
        Details: <br />
        @SelectedTestObject.Details;
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private List<Models.TestObject> TestObjects = new();
    private TestObject SelectedTestObject = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject
            {
                Id = 1,
                Text = "Test 1",
                Details = "Test 1 Details"
            });
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject
            {
                Id = 2,
                Text = "Test 2",
                Details = "Test 2 Details"
            });
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject
            {
                Id = 3,
                Text = "Test 3",
                Details = "Test 3 Details"
            });

        SelectedTestObject = TestObjects[0];
    }

    private void SelectObject(int SelectedId)
    {
        SelectedTestObject = TestObjects.Where(t => t.Id == SelectedId).FirstOrDefault();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick fix to the setup you are using, the resulting setup wont be best but its based on what you are trying to achieve

This is your TextComponent.razor

```
<button @onclick="Click" class="test" style="background-color: @(Selected? "grey" : "white");">
   @Text
</button>

[Parameter] public int Id { get; set; }
[Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
[Parameter] public bool Selected { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<int> CallBack { get; set; }

private void Click()
{
    CallBack.InvokeAsync(Id);
}
```

This is your TestParent.razor

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: white;">
@foreach (var T in TestObjects)
{
    <TestComponent Id="@T.Id" Text="@T.Text" Selected=@(T.Id==selectedId) CallBack="SelectObject" />
}

<hr />
<div>
    Details: <br />
    @SelectedTestObject.Details;
</div>
```

```
private List<TestObject> TestObjects = new();
private TestObject SelectedTestObject = new();

private int selectedId = 1;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    TestObjects.Add(new TestObject
        {
            Id = 1,
            Text = "Test 1",
            Details = "Test 1 Details"
        });
    TestObjects.Add(new TestObject
        {
            Id = 2,
            Text = "Test 2",
            Details = "Test 2 Details"
        });
    TestObjects.Add(new TestObject
        {
            Id = 3,
            Text = "Test 3",
            Details = "Test 3 Details"
        });

    SelectedTestObject = TestObjects[0];
}

private void SelectObject(int id)
{
    selectedId = id;
    SelectedTestObject = TestObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: thanks that is working. Can you explain the limitation of this approach and whether there's a better method I should be looking at? Also from what I can see the changes are around inline conditional statements rather than in a separate function. Why is this working and calling functions isn't? Thanks